# How do I stylize a blog page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a WordPress site for a client and want to know where the styling for the blog would be located. The blog can be viewed here http://ruthcrocker.whoistheoldguy.com/blog/. Pretty much what I want to do is make the whole blog page narrower and centered to match the styling of the rest of the site. Then place the categories and subscribers to the right and have the most recent blog posts in the middle. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

See [Theme Development](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) in the Wordpress Manual.

Answer (score 0):

The basic stylesheet is located here:

`http://ruthcrocker.whoistheoldguy.com/wp-content/themes/ruth/styles/style.css`

But I would have a look at:

`http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development`

For development instructions and advice